# LocationStrategy.pushState(state: any, title: string, url: string, queryParams: string) - What is state?

Tags: angular, browser-history

What can I do with the state argument in `pushState(state: any, title: string, url: string, queryParams: string)` ?

Can I store data ?

Is there any documentation out there that would be more 'detailed' than https://angular.io/api/common/LocationStrategy#pushState ?

<3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `pushState` function will ultimately map to the browser's `history.pushState` function in one way or another. The MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) gives a detailed description of how this `state` property is used:

> The state object is a JavaScript object which is associated with the new history entry created by `pushState()`. Whenever the user navigates to the new state, a `popstate` event is fired, and the `state` property of the event contains a copy of the history entry's state object.
>
> **The state object can be anything that can be serialized.** Because Firefox saves state objects to the user's disk so they can be restored after the user restarts the browser, we impose a size limit of 640k characters on the serialized representation of a state object. If you pass a state object whose serialized representation is larger than this to `pushState()`, the method will throw an exception. If you need more space than this, you're encouraged to use `sessionStorage` and/or `localStorage`.

(Emphasis mine/OP's).

The `popstate` event described here is available in Angular via its [`Location`](https://angular.io/api/common/Location) service. Specifically, you can [subscribe](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#subscribe) to the `Location` service in order to listen for [`PopStateEvent`](https://angular.io/api/common/PopStateEvent)s, which include a `state` property containing what you would expect.